# Hostname resolution different on both WiFi bands

Tags: wifi, routers

I have a couple of devices that have a defined hostname, to which I can access/reach on both my browser and command line (using `ping`) when I am connected to my home network via LAN and 5GHz WiFi, but I can't reach them via the browser when I am on my 2.4GHz WiFi. I am using my ISP's router with un-changed networking/routing properties, and I can access all devices if using their IPs.

Could this be anything related to my browser settings, caching for example?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that from the same computer or different devices? If different, did you by any chance change your /etc/hosts (or equivalent) on one of them? Are those regular names (in public DNS) or mDNS-type names?   Or even Windows names…? What OS are you using?

Comment: Short answer: I don't know. Longer rambling: There maybe some "allow devices to interoperate" or "secure guest devices" or some option like that enabled on the 2.4 part (though, they should operate at the IP level actually). Try doing a trace route or a whois query to see if the name resolution is succeeding even. Maybe it somehow uses a different DNS when using the 2.4 interface.